# How do I change the frame style in C# code?

Tags: xamarin.forms

It's pretty simple, but I can't figure it out. I have an xml file with the specified frame and its name(Enter). How do I style it in C# code (color, size)? Make changes in the MainPage class.xaml.cs ? Thank you for your help !

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         x:Class="TaxiCity.MainPage">
    <Grid>
       <Frame x:Name="Enter">

       </Frame>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: The Frame that you have given the name `x:Name="Enter"` will now be available in your C# code behind in that pages xaml.cs which would be correct place to handle this

Comment: Please provide an example code. I so understand my method such:   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void EnterFrame()
        {

        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with **@FreakyAli** ,  Since you have set the x:name of Frame , you can directly access it in Code behind .

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  EnterFrame();
}

public void EnterFrame() { 

  Enter.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
  Enter.WidthRequest = 500;
  Enter.HeightRequest = 500;
}
```